# "Assume something be" or "Assume something is"?

Tags: clauses, mathematics, optional-that

I am writing a scientific paper.

I am not sure about the usage of "assume."

Should I say "Let us assume x is real," or should I say "Let us assume x be real"?

Comment: Your final alternative suggests you may be confusing the construction *Let's assume [statement] [**is a true statement**]* with the textbook standard *Let [variable] **be** [value]*.

Comment: Just so it's said, "sth" is not a word. I wish its use would die.

Comment: What is "sth"...it shows up a ton in the Related sidebar

Comment: @NickT It's an abbreviation for "something".

Answer (score 15):

> Let us assume x is real

This sounds about right.

> Let us assume x be real

This is grammatically incorrect.

> Let us assume x *to* be real

This is grammatically correct, but sounds awkward, though with more context, it could be more correct than *is*.

Comment: In some contexts, "Let x be [any] real" works also.  (And FWIW, in a paper/proof, the "to be" construction above would sound perfectly fine to me.)

Answer (score 5):

Your question has made me think about this for the first time: there seems to be a distinction between verbs that merely process information about a fixed situation, and verbs that declare a position or approach to a potentially changeable situation.

For example you would say

> I believe [that] X *is* real.

and not "I believe X be real". By contrast you should really say

> I demand [that] X *be* real.

and not "I demand X is real".

One result of this is that the following two statements have different meaning:

> I insist that X is real

means "I emphatically believe that the proposition 'X is real' describes the current situation correctly, independent of my intervention or yours",  whereas

> I insist that X be real

means something along the lines of "I am laying down the law, that you must ensure X is real",  or more  generally "X may be real or not, but if it is not real then I will refuse to proceed/cooperate with whatever we're talking about".

Your example, of *assuming* whether something is real, is processing information about a fixed proposition. Therefore you would not use the subjunctive. You would say  "assume that X is real", not "assume that X be real".

In a mathematical paper where are you are describing your initial conditions, you can choose whether to use the metaphor of actively creating X as you define it ("*let* X *be* a real number") or the metaphor of merely describing the state of an already-defined entity ("*assume* X *is* a real number"). The former is probably more common.

Comment: Constructions like "I demand that X be real" and "I insist that X be real" use the [English present subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive).